# Annihilator as a maximal ideal

Tags: modules, group-rings

Let $R[G]$ be the group ring of a finite group $G$ over a commutative ring $R$ with $1$. Let $S$ be a simple $R[G]$-module and let $I$ be the annihilator in $R$ of $S$. Show that $I$ is a maximal ideal in $R$.

What I have so far: Suppose $I\subseteq M\subseteq R$ for some ideal $M$ and $M\neq I$, then pick $m\in M-I$. For a non-zero $x\in S$, $m\cdot x=y$ for some $0\neq y\in S$. Since $S$ is a simple $R[G]$-module, $x=(\sum_{i=1}^nr_ig_i)y$ for some $r_1,...,r_n\in R$ and $g_1,...,g_n\in G$. Then $m\sum_{i=1}^nr_ig_i-1$ annihilates $y$. I don't know how I can conclude that $m$ is a unit in $R$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ be the annihilator of $S$ in $R[G]$, so $P\cap R=I$.
Since $R[G]$ is finitely generated as an $R$-module, it follows that $S$ is finitely generated as an $R$-module.  Thus $S$ has a maximal (proper) $R$-submodule $N$.  For each $g\in G$, the set $gN$ is an $R$-submodule of $S$.  It is easy to see that $gN\cong N$ and $S/gN\cong S/N$ as $R$-modules.  If we let $J$ denote the annihilator of $S/N$ (and hence of each $S/gN$) in $R$, then $J$ is a maximal ideal since $S/N$ is simple.

The intersection $\cap_{g\in G}\, gN$ is a proper $R[G]$-submodule of $S$, since it's closed under multiplication by $R$ and $G$.  Thus $\cap_{g\in G}\, gN=0$.  As usual, this implies that $S$ embeds in $\oplus_{g\in G}\, S/gN$ as an $R$-module.  As noted above, the direct sum is annihilated by $J$ and so $S$ is annihilated by $J$.  Hence $J\subseteq P\cap R$. But $J$ is maximal, so we must have $J=P\cap R$, proving that $I=P\cap R$ is a maximal ideal of $R$.

*Edited* because my notation didn't agree with the OP.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use PI theory, here's a proof.  Let $P$ be the annihilator of $S$ in $R[G]$.  The ideal $P$ is primitive by definition and the ring $R[G]$ is a PI (polynomial identity) ring since it's a finitely generated module over a commutative ring.  Kaplansky's Theorem implies primitive ideals in PI rings are maximal.

**Edit:** This answer is the wrong conclusion because I misread the problem.  This shows $P$ is maximal, but the OP wants to show $P\cap R$ is maximal.  However, Kaplansky's Theorem in this situation also says that $P\cap R$ is maximal.

Comment: Hi, I tried to solve this question from first principles without a lot of progress. Do you know how or whether the finiteness of $G$ is being used here?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't know much about PI theory. Are there any easier ways to prove this?

Comment: @Greg Nisbet  The result does not hold if $G$ is infinite.  For example, Formanek [showed](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(73)90011-2) that the group ring $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ is primitive for any non-Abelian free group $G$, but $0$ is not a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$.