# Is a module simple if and only if the base ring modded by the annihilator congruence is a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let rings be commutative and unital and modules be two-sided.

I was reading [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4834257/annihilator-as-a-maximal-ideal/4834289) and thinking of ways to solve it.

This got me wondering whether a fairly basic fact about $R$-modules is true.

An $R$-module is simple if and only if it has exactly two submodules, or, equivalently, exactly two congruences.

The annihilator of an $R$-module $M$ is an ideal of $R$, as a congruence of $R$ it is the finest congruence associated with $M$.

Does this mean that $M$ is a simple $R$-module precisely when $R\big/\!\equiv_{\text{Ann}(M)}$ is a field?

I guess what I'm asking is, *is it possible that a non-simple $R$-module $M$ has a nonzero proper submodule $W$ that we can't find by inspecting $R\big/\!\equiv_{\text{Ann}(M)}$*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding the question, but let $F$ be a field.  Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $2$ over $F$.  The annihilator of $V$ is the set of all $a\in F$ such that $av=0$ for all $v\in V$.  But if $a\in F$, $a\ne 0$ then $(1/a)av=v\ne 0$ for all non-zero $v$, so $av\ne 0$, so $a$ is not in the annihilator.  So the annihilator is $\{0\}\subseteq F$ and $F/\text{Ann} \cong F$ which is a field.  But $V$ is not simple.  Any $1$-dimensional subspace is a proper non-zero sub-module.

Comment: Yep, that's true and it works for any nontrivial vector space. The annihilator is always $(0)$. Thanks.